# Using purrr::map and forcats::fct_reorder to reorder factor levels by each subgroup

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr, purrr, forcats

I'm trying to reorder the factor levels of a variable within each subgroup of that variable based on a third variable but I'm getting an error.

I recognize this is a little difficult to understand without context, so I'm using the `gapminder` dataset to illustrate. Here, I want to re-order the factor levels of the `country` variable within each category of the `continent` variable based on the size of the `pop` variable:

```
library(gapminder)
library(tidyverse)
library(forcats)

gapminder %>% 
    filter(year == 2007) %>% 
    group_by(continent) %>% 
    nest() %>% 
    mutate(newdata = map(data, fct_reorder, country, pop)) %>% 
    unnest(newdata)
```

> ```
> Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
> `f` must be a factor (or character vector).
> ```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Since `data` is a data.frame, you'd need syntax like `gapminder::gapminder %>% 
    filter(year == 2007) %>% 
    group_by(continent) %>% 
    nest() %>% 
    mutate(newdata = map(data, ~mutate(.x, country = forcats::fct_reorder(country, pop)))) %>% 
    unnest(newdata)`, but you've still got the conflicting levels issue mentioned below. You should edit with your larger goal; there may be a better approach.

Comment: Thanks @alistaire. I'm now leaning towards "manually" establishing the levels of the factors in a separate vector to avoid the issue altogether.

Comment: What's the point of using factors anyway? Aside from setting orders in plots or manually setting contrasts for a model, strings are usually just as or more useful.

Comment: @alistaire It is to set order in a plot.

Comment: Then you should ask that question.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really now `forcats` and its `fct_*` functions, I poked around and didn't find a way to accomplish what you want. However we can obtain it with:

```r
library(gapminder)
library(tidyverse)

gapminder %>% 
  filter(year == 2007) %>% 
  group_by(continent) %>% 
  nest() %>% 
  mutate(newdata = map(data, ~{
    .x$country <- reorder(.x$country, order(.x$pop, decreasing = TRUE))
    .x
    })
  ) -> res
res
#> # A tibble: 5 × 3
#>   continent              data           newdata
#>      <fctr>            <list>            <list>
#> 1      Asia <tibble [33 × 5]> <tibble [33 × 5]>
#> 2    Europe <tibble [30 × 5]> <tibble [30 × 5]>
#> 3    Africa <tibble [52 × 5]> <tibble [52 × 5]>
#> 4  Americas <tibble [25 × 5]> <tibble [25 × 5]>
#> 5   Oceania  <tibble [2 × 5]>  <tibble [2 × 5]>
```

We can verify that the factor levels really changed:

```r
lapply(res$newdata, function(x) as.numeric(x$country))
#> [[1]]
#>  [1]  5  7  8 23  3 12 24 31  9 30 15 20  1 21 25 10 18 14 29 33 27 28  4
#> [24]  6 11 13 26 32 17 22 19 16  2
#> 
#> [[2]]
#>  [1] 11 29 10 30 16 26 20 22 18 12 21  3  7 23 13 27  2 28  5  8 24  9 19
#> [24]  4  6 15  1 25 17 14
#> 
#> [[3]]
#>  [1] 37 15 18 11 44 45 47 24 33  1 50 21 34 28 13  7  5 29 36  2 52 41 30
#> [24] 51 49  9 22 43 39  6  3 42 27 48 17  8 12 31 26 35 25 20  4 23 19 32
#> [47] 46 38 10 16 14 40
#> 
#> [[4]]
#>  [1] 23  3 16  6  1  4 20 25  5 10 12  8  9  2 13 14 11 19 17  7 21 24 18
#> [24] 15 22
#> 
#> [[5]]
#> [1] 1 2
```

After this you can't really `unnest` it, as the country factor 'list' for each `continent` would conflict with the others:

```r
res %>% 
  select(-data) %>% 
  unnest() -> res2
sapply(res2$country, as.numeric)
#>   [1]   5   7   8  23   3  12  24  31   9  30  15  20   1  21  25  10  18
#>  [18]  14  29  33  27  28   4   6  11  13  26  32  17  22  19  16   2  34
#>  [35]  39  40  43  46  60  62  63  72  73  76  78  84  85  86  87  99 103
#>  [52] 108 112 113 116 120 122 123 126 129 130 135 137  35  36  41  44  47
#>  [69]  48  49  51  52  55  56  57  59  64  67  69  70  71  74  75  77  80
#>  [86]  81  89  90  91  92  93  94  95  96  97 100 101 102 106 107 115 117
#> [103] 118 119 121 124 125 127 128 131 132 134 136 141 142  37  42  45  50
#> [120]  53  54  58  61  65  66  68  79  82  83  88  98 105 109 110 111 114
#> [137] 133 138 139 140  38 104
```

I think they are reordered again sequentially.

Comment: "After this you can't really unnest it, as the factor 'list' for each continent would conflict with the others"

Of course... Don't know what I didn't think about this issue. Hmm, back to the drawing board.